# Jumping While Pushing Through Fire Makes A Difference?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If there's fire on the ground. Do you take less damage if you jump through it rather than running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you're in it, you'll burn. It doesn't matter, where exactly you are (airborne or on the ground that is).

A regular jump would slow you down to even take more fire damage from the Molotov than just running through it.

Comment: Do you recon it would make a difference if I bunny-hop before entering the molotov flames?

Comment: @Mano It's about the time spent in the fire. So if you're at a decent bhop speed (e.g. from jumping downhill) that would probably help.